# Apache CXF Plugin 3.3.12 & 3.4.5 not working under Java 11?

Tags: cxf, maven-plugin

I am trying to update my tool chain from Java 8 to 11.
Doing so I run into issues compiling WSDLs to java using the Apache CXF maven plugin.

I tried with the latest two available versions:
org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.12 and
org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.4.5

When I run the `wsdl2java` goal (phase `generate-sources`) it first seems to read all the WSDLs and XSDs ok but at the end it invariably ends in compile errors (see below). So it seems as if it generates code that can't be compiled under Java 11!?!

What dependencies do I need to add? Or what other steps are necessary to get this working again?

Error:

```
...
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/KStA_ZH_ZHQuest/code/application/zhquest-sam-web-service/target/generated-sources/cxf/ch/adnovum/nevisidm/ws/services/v1_37/AdminServicePortImpl.java:[10,17] package javax.jws does not exist
...
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/KStA_ZH_ZHQuest/code/application/zhquest-sam-web-service/target/generated-sources/cxf/ch/adnovum/nevisidm/ws/services/v1_37/AdminServicePortImpl.java:[14,22] package javax.jws.soap does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/Projects/KStA_ZH_ZHQuest/code/application/zhquest-sam-web-service/target/generated-sources/cxf/ch/adnovum/nevisidm/ws/services/v1_37/AdminServicePortImpl.java:[15,33] package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
```

Note: I *am* aware of these threads: [CXF codegen maven plugin doesn't work OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857820/cxf-codegen-maven-plugin-doesnt-work-openjdk-11) and [What dependencies do I need to run Apache CXF with Spring Boot on Java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57191209/what-dependencies-do-i-need-to-run-apache-cxf-with-spring-boot-on-java-11#58537054) but the dependencies suggested in either *did not* fix my issue.